# How can I split table rows into some equal parts for future processing?

Tags: sql, oracle, pagination

Given we have some table. It is to big to be processed in one step by our application, and also we want to parallelize the processing of it by multiple threads of our application. So we need to split table into some parts. How can we write a query which returns that parts of a table?

For example, here is my table:

```
id   name   age
1    John   25
2    Peter  34
3    Anna   18
```

I want to process this table by 3 threads. So I need to write a query which splits the rows into 3 parts. What is the most effective way to do this?

I am using Oracle, but it is interesting to know the answers for all main databases if they differ.

PS
I just realized that this looks like a typical pagination query. As far as I understand in Oracle pagination is done using a query like this:

```
select * 
  from ( select /*+ FIRST_ROWS(n) */ 
  a.*, ROWNUM rnum 
      from ( your_query_goes_here, 
      with order by ) a 
      where ROWNUM <= 
      :MAX_ROW_TO_FETCH ) 
where rnum  >= :MIN_ROW_TO_FETCH;
```

(from here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-sep/o56asktom-086197.html)

But may be we can benefit something from the fact we know the pages are equal? Also we need some preliminary query to fetch total row number to divide it into parts later. May be we can incorporate that query into main one? 
Also I guess same task can be solved via ntile function in Oracle. Which solution is better? Is there any other solutions?

Comment: Why do you think using three threads will be faster?  Do you have any empirical data to back that up?  Do some testing.  Oracle has parallel query support built in.  What do you mean, your table is "too big?"

Comment: OldProgrammer it will be faster to process this data, not to read. I can read the data in any way: by one thread, by three, but I want to process it in parallel way by several threads.

Comment: So my question is not about parallel read of Oracle table but about how to split it for parallel processing of that data.